# Tab indicator and slide like Material Design with Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, swipe, touch-event

[image: example]

I've tried to make the Material Design Slide Indicator (watch image) with javascript.

I use Ionic to control the slides (to "swipe", to set slide or to obtain the current slide) but the prolem doesn't regard it.
I've tried whit `$swipe` and with pure js, the problem is the same.

When I swipe on the slide, I  would like the indicator moved below the swipe (like in YouTube app), but **the indicator moves slightly delayed**.

I've do an example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bmfva858/5/) with comments, I've made it with a yellow div to simule the swipe area and a red indicator. I've tested it with my smartphone.
In my example I move the indicator changing the margin-left.

How can I do the indicator more reactive? There is another method?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the delay problem!

```
#linea {
  height: 5px;
  width: 33.333%;
  background:red;
  transition: 300ms /*<-- THIS IS THE PROBLEM*/
```

}